# VBA Factory with VB_PredeclaredId = True vs "anonymous" instance pros and cons

Tags: vba, oop, factory

Curios what are advantages/disadvantages between Factory with VB_PredeclaredId = True and "anonymous" instance in VBA. Each for its own scenarios or better stick to one of them and why? Any feedback or links where I can read more about it would be appreciated! Thank you!

Worksheet data staring A1

```
Name    Manager Target
Person1 Manager1    97
Person2 Manager2    92
Person3 Manager3    95
Person4 Manager4    105
Person5 Manager5    108
Person6 Manager6    88
```

Factory - Class

```
'@Folder("VBAProject")

Option Explicit
'@PredeclaredId

Public Function getPerson(ByVal name As String, ByVal manager As String, ByVal target As Double) As Person
    With New Person
        .name = name
        .manager = manager
        .Targer = target
        Set getPerson = .self
    End With
End Function
```

Person - Class

```
Private pName As String
Private pManager As String
Private pTarger As Double

Public Property Get Targer() As Double
    Targer = pTarger
End Property

Public Property Let Targer(ByVal value As Double)
    pTarger = value
End Property


Public Property Get manager() As String
    manager = pManager
End Property

Public Property Let manager(ByVal value As String)
    pManager = value
End Property


Public Property Get name() As String
    name = pName
End Property

Public Property Let name(ByVal value As String)
    pName = value
End Property

Public Function toString() As String
    toString = "Name: " & Me.name & ", Manager: " & Me.manager & ", Targer: " & Me.Targer
End Function

Public Function self() As Person
    Set self = Me
End Function
```

Test - Module

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To 6

    With New Person
        .name = Range("A" & i)
        .manager = Range("b" & i)
        .Targer = Range("c" & i)
        Debug.Print .toString
    End With

    Debug.Print Factory.getPerson(name:=Range("A" & i), _
                manager:=Range("B" & i), target:=Range("C" & i)).toString

    'or shorter whithout feild names
    Debug.Print Factory.getPerson(Range("A" & i), Range("B" & i), Range("C" & i)).toString

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Reading again, I'm not clear what the dichotomy is... an anonymous object would be `With New Person...End With`, and the `Factory` class you have there is really a `PersonFactory`. I would oppose a *factory method* on the `Person` class to a `PersonFactory` class or module... `With...End With` creates an object, but it's extremely localized in scope - anonymous objects are just a code construct in your toolbox, whereas factory method, factory classes, abstract factories, are design patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** It's apples and bananas, really. Anonymous objects are a language constructs; factories aren't defined in the language specs, they're more of a *design pattern*, and yes, there are different reasons to use each different approach - although IMO a "factory <s>bag</s> module" is a bad idea.

---

#### Anonymous Objects

Anonymous objects are awesome - you get to invoke members on an object that's held by a `With` block, without needing to add a local variable. That's `With New`, but it's also particularly useful with `With CreateObject`:

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    '...
End With
```

They create objects, but such objects are (normally - a `.Self` getter can thwart that) confined to the containing `With` block; anonymous objects are useful for objects you need *right here & now*, and no longer need beyond that point. They are a *language feature*, basically.

**Factory Class** (or module)

We're leaving the realm of *language features*, and entering that of *design patterns*. Now we're talking about encapsulating the relatively complex creation of a given object, inside a class dedicated to that purpose.

The `VB_PredeclaredId = True` attribute (whether set by a `@PredeclaredId` Rubberduck annotation or not) makes that class work like any other standard module.

The problem with a `Factory` class that exposes a `getPerson` (or `CreatePerson`) method, is that you now have an excuse to extend this with some `getAnotherThing` (or `CreateAnotherThing`), and before you know it you're looking at a class/module that's able to create just about anything, whether these things are even remotely related or not.

Surely there's a better way.

**Factory Method**

What if a `Person` object knew how to create a new instance of the `Person` class?

```
Set p = Person.Create(1188513, "Mathieu")
```

This requires having the `VB_PredeclaredId = True` attribute on the `Person` class, and `Person`'s *default interface* to expose a `Create` method to be invoked from that default instance.

The problem is that now anything that consumes a `Person` object is now seeing a confusing API that exposes `Property Let` members for `ID` and `Name` properties, and a `Create` function that's only meant to be used from the default instance.

This problem has a solution though: the only code that's "allowed" to work with `Person`, should be code that's responsible for invoking the `Create` factory method on that type. Everything else only ever sees an `IPerson` - an explicit interface that `Person` implements to define how the rest of the code shall interact with an object of that type... and `IPerson` does not need to expose any `Property Let` members, or `Create` method.

There's another problem that the pattern doesn't solve though - imagine `IPerson` is implemented by two or more classes (say, `Employee` and `Manager`): even if the entire project only ever sees `IPerson`, there's still some code in there that's calling `Employee.Create` or `Manager.Create`, and that code is inherently *coupled* with these specific implementations of the `IPerson` interface. It's a problem, because such coupling essentially negates the benefits of coding against interfaces in the first place.

**Abstract Factory**

In order to decouple the code that's creating `IPerson` objects from `Employee` and `Manager` classes, we could create an `IPersonFactory` interface that abstracts the factory method itself: now the code consuming the factory and create `IPerson` objects doesn't even know what concrete type of objects it's creating, and the decoupling is complete.

You probably don't need that level of decoupling unless you have everything covered with a thorough suite of unit tests, but it's useful to know it exists regardless.

So you would have `EmployeeFactory` and `ManagerFactory` classes, both implementing `IPersonFactory` and supplying an implementation for some `Create` function that returns an `IPerson` object.

...to be honest this is where the person/employee example kind of falls apart, because such a class is more of a simple DTO (Data Transfer Object - i.e. a bunch of public fields, or read/write properties) than anything that actually has responsibilities - so let's drop it.

We'll have a `SqlConnectionFactory`, an `OracleConnectionFactory`, and a `MySqlConnectionFactory`, all implementing some `IDbConnectionFactory` to yield some `IDbConnection` object that encapsulates, you'll have guessed, a database connection.

So we could have code that looks like this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(ByVal factory As IDbConnectionFactory)
    Dim pwd As String
    pwd = InputBox("SA Password?") 'bad example: now we're coupled with the InputBox API!

    Dim conn As IDbConnection
    Set conn = factory.Create("server name", "sa", pwd)

    '...
End Sub
```

That `DoSomething` method would be able to do its thing against an SQL Server, Oracle, or MySQL database server, *and never needs to care which one it's actually working with*.

*Abstract Factory* is useful when you're injecting dependencies (c.f. "dependency injection") that themselves have dependencies that you cannot resolve until last-minute, for example because you need some parameter that the user needs to provide through some UI (which is itself ideally also abstracted behind an interface, so that you can unit-test the method without popping that UI - although, Rubberduck's `Fakes` API does allow you to hijack an `InputBox`... imagine we're popping a `UserForm` instead).

Comment: By my first impressions, Factory Method/Abstract Factory look more concise. But Anonymous objects also have their own charm, I think it's more readable. So for complicated classes, it is better to use Abstract factory, whereas for DTO you can use both Abstract factories and Anonymous objects. You mentioned `You probably don't need that level of decoupling`. Is Abstract factory for DTO overkill or good manners?

Comment: You mentioned `there are different reasons to use each different approach`. Do you have any other examples/situations aside `With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`? You mentioned `IMO a "factory bag module" is a bad idea.`. Could you please elaborate why do you think so? Does it matter if we have a lot or just a couple of properties/methods in a class? Would it make one approach more preferable over another? Or everything is up to you and quite subjective. 
PS. I love Rubberduck! You are doing great work! Thank you for that!

Comment: The key is that you don't implement design patterns just for the heck of it, e.g. you use an *abstract factory* because it allows you to decouple the dependencies of a class you want to be able to write tests for; a "factory bag" is just a global-scope "I can create anything" module that keeps everything coupled and continually grows to contain more and more completely unrelated methods... the antithesis of *Single Responsibility* and *Interface Segregation* principles, to name a few: it's inherently anti-OOP; use it in procedural spaghetti ;-)

Comment: Each has different abstraction levels: you would use `With New ADODB.Connection` in a class where coupling to ADODB.Connection is expected and acceptable; that class would be decoupled from its consumers through an interface, and created by an abstract factory, whose implementation uses a factory method. If you're not trying to decouple classes and improve testability, then all of it is massive overkill since `New`ing up the class you want to work with remains the simplest way to get things to work... if you don't mind the coupling. You'll want to read on *dependency injection* for more! =)